# Google Maps API key not used

Tags: android, google-maps

I developed an Android app that originally used Google Maps APIs. In development, however, I moved to an implementation without the API (and without a key), using an Intent to which I pass a URL of the path and its functions (navigator for example). Now my project is still registered to the Google Maps API service. Will I be forced to pay something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, you would not have to pay.  According to google you pay based on usage: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/

"Pay only for what you use
Our pricing scales to fit your needs with no commitments, termination fees, or usage limits — and you can use mobile Maps at no charge."